# How do I convert between the different co-ord systems for Ray Tracing?

Tags: coordinate-systems, linear-transformations

I am having trouble understanding how to convert (and what to convert) for my ray tracing program. At the moment I only have 3D to 2D projection transformation which is used to project the 3D world onto the 2D screen. However, it doesn't seem to be working because I can logically predict which pixels should have colour data and which shouldn't, for a simple case. (e.g: Make a 2x2 viewport and a sphere which is larger than the viewport and is close to it. I can expect all pixels to have data since there will be a definite intersection with the object, yet I don't get any.)

The transformation I am using is:

$$x_{scene} = \frac{z_{max} * x_{pixel}}{D}$$
$$y_{scene} = \frac{z_{max} * y_{pixel}}{D}$$
$$z_{scene} = z_{max}$$

Where $z_{max}$ is the depth of the scene, $D$ is the distance from the viewport (screen) to the observer. I am using this transformation for the $x,y,z$ co-ords for each ray that passes through the viewport (i.e: one ray per pixel), to see where this ray is in the scene

**Is this correct? What other transformations am I missing out?**

Comment: I have found that while it might be "slow", running the "fast line" maker in $3$D with starting point at the observer, reference point is each pixel at a time at the viewport and going until there is a collision within the viewed space is an effective approach.

Comment: Note that the fast line algorithm does not depend on distances to operate, just a pair of coordinates to traverse.

Comment: Well, your notation is quite messy, but formulas seems to be reasonable. To clear things out, I'd say that projection of pinhole camera sends point $(x_{scene}, y_{scene}, z_{scene})$ to point $(D \cdot \frac{x_{scene}}{z_{scene}}, D \cdot \frac{y_{scene}}{z_{scene}})$